# How to set the x-axis in a Seaborn Scatterplot

Tags: data-visualization, seaborn, scatter-plot

After plotting my data using seaborn scatterplot, it looks like this. Now in this graph most of the data appears in the year 2013-2017, so i tried to set the x-axis limit to 2013-2017 but i am not able to achieve the same

[image]

**i tried this**

```
g.set_xticks(range(1,7)) # <--- set the ticks first 
g.set_xticklabels(['2012','2013','2014','2015','2016','2017'])
```

**this**

```
ax.set_xticks(['2012','2013','2014','2015','2016','2017','2018'])
```

**and this**

```
g.set(xlim=(pd.date_range('2012',periods=7)))
```

but i am not able to set my x-axis from 2013-2017, this is my code

```
fig,_ax=plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(15,7))
sns.scatterplot(data=some_data_from_data_base,ax=_ax)
```

[my kaggle notebook link](https://www.kaggle.comnotebookb5859082e6)

Comment: Link doesn't work. Are you feeding NaN values for the empty years?

Comment: @runDOSrun, please loggin to kaggle and then try tom access the link, it will work, thanks